# Can someone identify this scrapped high-wing plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

I consider myself to be a decent aircraft identifier, and when I saw this plane when exploring an aircraft graveyard, I was not able to identify it. I took a pic and showed it to several aviation Facebook groups, and nobody was able to identify it. Maybe we’re just being dumb and it’s something simple, but can somebody help? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: The N-number is still there on the tail you could use that in one of the registration databases.

Comment: @ratchetfreak - partially there. Can *you* make it out?

Comment: @Jamiec Not in this picture but the original non-scaled image may have it more readable.

Comment: Cpt Reynolds It was found in Discount Aircraft Salvage, an Aircraft Graveyard is Deer Park, WA.

Answer (score 25):

It's an [Aermacchi AL-60-B1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aermacchi_AL-60) (original design by Al Mooney, Lockheed L-402 Bushmaster aka Lockheed 60)

[image: aermacchi AL-60-B1]
([source](https://abpic.co.uk/pictures/model/Aermacchi%20AL.60-B1))

[image: lockheed 60]
([source](http://imgproc.airliners.net/photos/airliners/6/7/4/0751476.jpg?v=v40))

Comment: Looks like a match, but how did you figure this out? Nice work.

Comment: @dvnrrs For people who are knowledgeable on identifying aircraft no "figuring out" is required. Shape of the wings (even just the roots), the windows/cabin, the empenage, the tail (or what is left of it)

Comment: Thank you! I figured out the registration by looking at it very closely from a different angle. N3380G; A Lockheed-Aermacchi Model 402-2, a MUCH rarer prototype variant of the Lockheed 60.

Answer (score 4):

If that is N3380G, I saw it at EAA Airventure Oshkosh in 2001.  It was a Mexican built model, not Italian.  I have a pic of the dataplate showing Lockheed-Azcarate S.A., AeroGuayin, Model LASA-60, S/N 1010.